Adding WaymarkedTrails maps (Lonvia Hiking Lonvia Cycling) into QGIS
I would really like to turn QGIS into an equivalent of Maperitive.
Ideally I would like to import Web Maps (OSM Mapnik, Lonvia Hiking and Cycling), Geometry Data I downloaded from https://www.viewfinderpanoramas.org/Coverage%20map%20viewfinderpanoramas_org3.htm , and spit out PNGs of it.
The plugin WEB2QGIS https://github.com/tomchadwin/web2qgis that I've seen mentioned here isn't working if I try to import the website cycling.waymarkedtrails.org in it, nor does it work as a WMS, WFS, etc. etc.
I was able to use the geometry data with the Raster > Extraction > Level Curves functionality, and I was also able to import OMS tiles through XYZmap. Right now, the only workaround I've found to import waymarked trails info was by downloading it through overpass turbo with the following code (this is, for example, just for cycling trails):
   (
  relation
    [route=bicycle]
    [type=route]
    ({{bbox}});
  
  relation
    [route=bicycle]
    [type=superroute]
    ({{bbox}});
);
out geom;

and exporting it into the form of GPX and then importing it into QGIS (with some corruption issues, had to import only the line data or it would otherwise show some corrupted "phantom" trails).
However, I still am missing the step to make it show in a nice way with labelling similar to how it's done on Waymarked Trails.

Did you find a solution?
